# Not resetting password

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to make a reset password script thing but it didn't work, it doesn't update the database for some reason.

Code:

```
    <?php 
include 'header.php';

error_reporting(0);
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$userid = $_SESSION['id'];

 if (empty($username) && empty($userid) ) {

$form='
            <table>
            <form action="forgotpass.php" method="POST">
                <tr>
                    <td>Username :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="user"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
                    <td>Must be a valid email address.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="resetbtn" value="Reset password"></td>
                </tr>
                </form>
            </table> ';

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if (isset($_POST['resetbtn'])) { 

        if ($user) {

                if ($email) {

                    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

                        require 'core/connect.php';

                        $query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user' ");
                        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                        if ($numrows == 1) {
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
                        $dbemail = $row['email'];

                            if ($email = $dbemail) {

                               function better_crypt($input, $rounds = 7) {
                               $salt = "";
                               $salt_chars = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range(0,9));
                               for($i=0; $i < 22; $i++) {
                               $salt .= $salt_chars[array_rand($salt_chars)];
                               }
                               return crypt($input, sprintf('$2a$%02d$', $rounds) . $salt);
                               }
                               $password_hash = better_crypt($password);
                               $password_hash = better_crypt($password, 10);
                               $password_hash = better_crypt($password, 15);
                               $new_pass = substr($password_hash, 0, 15);

                                mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "UPDATE users SET password = '$new_pass' WHERE username = '$username' ");
                                $query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user' AND password = '$new_pass' ");
                                $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                                if ($numrows == 1) {

                                    $site = "http://localhost/website";
                                    $webmaster = "Demo Site<JadWalidSamadi@gmail.com>";
                                    $headers = "From: $webmaster";
                                    $subject = "Password reset";
                                    $message = "You have asked for a password reset for Demo Site.\n";
                                    $message = "New password :";
                                    $message = "$new_pass";
                                    $message .="You must change your password as soon as you re-log in.";

                                        if (mail ($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers)) {

                                        echo '<font color="green">Your new password has been sent to your email. </font>';
                                        echo $email;

                                        } else {

                                        echo '<font color="red">An error has occurred.Your activation email was not sent.</font>';   

                                        }                                   

                                }else {

                                echo '<font color="red">An error has occurred . Your password was not reset.</font>';   

                                }

                            }else{

                            echo '<font color="red">You have provided an invalid username or email.</font>';
                            echo $form;                                 

                            }

                        }else{

                        echo '<font color="red">You have provided an invalid username or email.</font>';
                        echo $form;                             

                        }

                        mysql_close();

                    } else {

                    echo '<font color="red">You must provide a valid email.</font>';
                    echo $form;                         

                    }

                } else {

                echo '<font color="red">You must provide your email.</font>';
                echo $form;                         

                }

        } else{

        echo '<font color="red">You must provide your username.</font>';
        echo $form;             

        }

    }else{

    echo $form;

    }

 }else{

    echo '<font color="red">You must be logged out to be able to access this page\'s content.</font>';   

 }

include 'footer.php';
 ?>
```

Comment: Well this doesn't help `error_reporting(0);` nor are you using `mysqli_error()` for `mysqli_query()`

Comment: i did remove it ...no errors what so

Comment: You have posted a lot of code which also looks pretty complex. Is there specific part of the code that is not working? Do you have error reporting turned on for your code ?

Comment: *"i did remove it"* - Doesn't help neither by "removing" it. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: error reporting is on and the only part that does not work in my code is editing the database (inserting new pass) ... so i guess the problem is related to the query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous errors, but the main ones are:

Line 64:

```
"UPDATE users SET password = '$new_pass' WHERE username = '$username' "
```

The variable `$username` MUST be empty, as this code is ran inside a conditional block with the following condition:

Line 9:

```
if (empty($username) && empty($userid) ) {
```

Probably you want to use the `$user` variable instead

Next, line 59:

```
$password_hash = better_crypt($password);
```

`$password` is undefined

Finally, line 78:

```
if (mail ($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
```

`$getemail` is undefined

Comment: Thank you. it was idiot mistakes from me. it worked.Thank you again.sorry for the disturb.

Comment: And 1 more: if ($email = $dbemail) is an assignment instead of a comparison, so this will always be true. Update to  if ($email == $dbemail) might help your code.

Also read about and use variable binding for your database queries. You code is not safe right now.

Comment: No problem - In future If you used a half decenty IDE (there are good free ones like Netbeans, and better paid ones, like phpstorm) then these errors are automatically highlighted for you